# Forcing Subdomains and Removing Subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am writing an app that will use basecamp style subdomains ([See post](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1512-how-to-do-basecamp-style-subdomains-in-rails)).

There are portions of the app that should **always be in a subdomain** and portions that should **never be in a subdomain**.  For example, the "home" page should never be in a subdomain, but the blogs and posts resources always should.  Keep in mind, I don't know the subdomains, as there is one per account.

I set up my routes like this (example).  It works well in that it matches the routes, but I am having difficulty forcing my app to link to the correct locations.

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  # these should all route to mysubdomain.myapp.com
  # Clicking on a post from myapp.com/categories/12 should take you to mysubdomain.myapp.com/posts/14
  constraints(Subdomain) do
    resources :blogs { resources :posts }
  end

  # these should all route to myapp.com (clicking on one of these links from mysubdomain.myapp.com should go to myapp.com/categories/12)
  constraints(NoSubDomain) do
    resources :categories
  end

end
```

The problem is that once I am in a subdomain, all of the links to the other pages (categories, etc) contain the subdomain.  I am not sure the best to solve this issue.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like could be done by overriding the `url_for` method to include a `:subdomain` option.

See the *Cleaning Up The Code To Change The Subdomain* section of RailsCasts #221.

Railscasts:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

ASCIIcasts:  http://asciicasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Then you could do something like:

```
<p><%= link_to "All Blogs", root_url(:subdomain => false) %></p>
```

Comment: I like this suggestion, and I saw it online earlier, however, I would need to do one of two things- Either override and set the default to false, and then pass in the subdomain in all of my links, or vice versa.  I was hoping that Rails would take a cue from my routes file, after all, that is what it is there for...

Comment: I understood that it was basically working, but that you wanted to ensure that specific paths, like "home" did not have a subdomain.  I thought you could use this override (:subdomain => false) on those links, and leave the rest as they were.  (If you don't pass :subdomain as an option, the existing functionality stays the same.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the key to your issue is that you need to use resource_name_url and not resource_name_path.

Path only gives you a relative URL (/accounts) vs url where it returns a full path (www.example.com/accounts).

Hope that helps,

Andrew

Comment: Just tried that.  The problem, unless I am just confused, is that you can't set the original url, so that doesn't do much.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way of doing this, and I'd love to know if there is, but what I've started doing for this is set the base domain name in my configuration (not Rails conf, but my own app configuration), then override the `root_url` helper to always go to the base domain name. You could use another name for that method, obviously, but I never use `base_url` for anything else so I kept it Rails-esque naming.